# HQL Query and Join with two unidirectional relationships

Tags: select, join, hql, where-clause

Please could you help with the following:

I have classes as follows:

```
class MasterAssociation {
    String name    
    Survey survey // can be null
    Object other
    // Lots of other attributes
}

class Survey {
    String name
    // Lots of other attributes
}

class SurveyQuestion {
    String name
    QuestionType type
    Survey survey
    // Lots of other attributes
}
```

(For various reasons the relationships above can only be uni-directional.)

I have a method that needs to return selected MasterAssociations based on a variety of criteria.  A new criteria that I have is to only return MasterAssociations that have a survey that contain a specific question type.  The existing code is all based on HQL, so I would like to keep it (I know the solution in SQL but do not really want to convert all the existing code nor create a special method just for this case).

How do I do the following? (this is pseudocode)

```
select MasterAssociation ma

// lots of existing code using different flags to construct query
// based on name, etc.

if (newSpecialFlag) {
    where ma.survey is not null
    and where ma.survey has SurveyQuestion.type = QuestionType.XYZ
}
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out (some Groovy syntax below, but it should still be readable)

I read elsewhere about modifying the original from clause to include a secondary object, even though the actual select does not select it.

Answer:

```
String hql = "select ma from MasterAssociation as ma"

if (newSpecialFlag) {
    hql += ", SurveyQuestion as sq "
    criteria += " AND sq.type = " + QuestionType.XYZ
    criteria += " AND ma.survey.id in (sq.survey.id) "
}
```